# Is there a rule of thumb for whether it's better to inject a pointer to a class or a pointer to its relevant members?

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, constructor, dependencies

In trying to reason about dependency injection with either a **pointer to class** or **pointers to the class's relevant members**, is there an established rule of thumb for which approach is more appropriate for a given relationship?

A simple example:

A Game class has an Actor class as a member variable.
The Actor class is dependent on some of Game's members.

Pseudo-Class:

```
  Game() {
   Actor* actor;
   AudioSys*audio;
   RenderSys* render;
   ...
}
```

**Approach 1:** Inject a pointer to the Game class

Pseudo-Constructor:

`Actor(Game*)`

**Approach 2:** Inject a pointer / pointers to the Game classes members

Pseudo-Constructor:

`Actor(AudioSys*, RenderSys* ...)`

My current understanding is that Approach 1 means:

- the code is less reuseable and cloaks the actual dependencies of the Actor class.
- the code leads to a requirement for forward declaration of classes due to the circular nature of dependencies (Game has an Actor and vice versa) which makes the code more difficult to read.
- any headers included in the Game class which the Actor class isn't dependent on will be unnecessarily recompiled.

whereas Approach 2 means:

- Actor's dependencies are clearer.
- Actor probably requires more constructor arguments.
- Constructor arguments used in the implementation of Actor aren't necessarily tied to Game which allows for cleaner, more flexible code.

In my mind approach 2 appears to be the better option in most situations and seems to lend itself to cleaner code. However, approach 1 was used throughout a popular C++ programming textbook by a developer with a much higher level of overall knowledge and experience than me (For both a Game - Actor relationship and a similar Actor - Component relationship), so I feel as though there's a good chance there's something I haven't quite cottoned on to.

Comment: You pretty much answered your question. Though in practice you want to evaluate every specific situation to pick, approach #2 will win most of the time. Btw, a popular programming textbook written when? Programming is a living field, and things that were considered good practices 15 years ago can be anti-patterns those days.

Comment: @RichardCritten> and give up on managing your object lifecycles… bad idea. For all practical purposes, a `shared_ptr` is pretty much the same thing as a global variable.

Comment: Assuming you have to inject any pointers or references *at all*  (which is not a given, except in very specific circumstances), the rule of thumb depends on how the various bits of data are grouped.   If pieces of data (or objects) can be unassociated with each other, then inject them separately.   If they are always associated with each other, inject an object that contains (or manages associations) with them.

Comment: @spectras It was published recently.